# Docker: cannot route docker container port to host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So I have a docker container up running, I tried to route its service port out to the host:

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  ai-recommender-server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3518:3518"
```

When the container is running, I can check it through "docker ps -a"

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                  COMMAND                  CREATED                  STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
ff940601a02f        recommender_ai-recommender-server                      "python server.py"       About an hour ago        Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:3518->3518/tcp   recommender_ai-recommender-server_1
```

When I tried to access from inside the container:

```
$ docker exec -it ff94 sh
/service # curl http://localhost:3518
{
  "message": "AI recommendation system"
}
```

But when I tried to do this on the host, I got the error "curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer"

```
$ curl http://localhost:3518
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Can anyone find out what my problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's python, I think binding to `0.0.0.0` may be missing in your python code

Something like this inside your python server.py

`app.run(debug='False',host='0.0.0.0',port=3518)`

Comment: so I have this in my python code:     app.run(host='localhost', port=3518, debug=True), are there any problems?

Comment: Yes. This won't work inside a docker container if using `localhost`. Check this [link](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/)

Comment: Thank you @Wander3r, it works! your link is very informative

Comment: @KenTsoi, please, mark this answer as solving your problem

Comment: Sorry forget to do that